# $injector:unpr Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- debounce

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I have the following controller in my app, which works fine on my machine. When I push to production and the code is minified, I get the following error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- debounce`. I'm struggling to debug this error. Almost every post I've found on the topic suggests that the problem is with my dependency injection, however I don't think that applies to my case.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap', 'ngFileUpload', 'rt.debounce']);

app.controller('SocialMediaCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$timeout', '$location', '$q', '$compile', 'socialMediaAPI', 'inspirationsAPI', 'debounce', 'modal', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $timeout, $location, $q, $compile, socialMediaAPI, inspirationsAPI, debounce, modal) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.newPost = {
        token: $scope.token,
        post: $scope.post,
        posts: {
            twitter: null,
            facebook: null,
            linkedin: null
        },
        attachment_url: $scope.attachment_url,
        media_url: $scope.media_url,
        services: {
            twitter: $scope.twitter,
            facebook: $scope.facebook,
            linkedin: $scope.linkedin
        }
    };

    function getTweetLength(post) {
        $scope.tweetLength = post ? 140 - twttr.txt.getTweetLength(post) : 0;
        if($scope.tweetLength < 0) {
            $scope.tweetLengthValidation = true;
        } else {
            $scope.tweetLengthValidation = false;
        };
    };

    function getLinkedInPostLength(post) {
        var url = twttr.txt.extractUrls(post)[0];
        if(post && url) {
            $scope.linkedInPostLength = 256 - post.length + url.length;
        } else if (post && !url) {
            $scope.linkedInPostLength = 256 - post.length;
        } else {
            $scope.linkedInPostLength = 0;
        };

        if($scope.linkedInPostLength < 0) {
            $scope.linkedInPostLengthValidation = true;
        } else {
            $scope.linkedInPostLengthValidation = false;
        };
    };

    var getLengthValidations = debounce(10, function(evt){
        getTweetLength($(evt.target).val());
        getLinkedInPostLength($(evt.target).val());
        if($scope.newPost.services.twitter) {
            $scope.maxLength = 140;
        } else if ($scope.newPost.services.linkedin) {
            $scope.maxLength = 256;
        } else {
            $scope.maxLength = 1000;
        };
    });

    $('textarea').on('keyup keydown cut paste', function(e){
        getLengthValidations(e);
    })
}]);
```

Note: The full controller is over 200 lines long, so I've omitted irrelevant parts for brevity.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the minified version of your `debounce` (and possibly others) with non-minified files to see if it is actually the minification that introduced the error in the first place? I have see some libraries not being minified (or introducing errors) because of some special characters not playing well with the minifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems to be indicating that the `debounce` provider instance is requiring the `e` provider instance. The problem is most likely not in your controller code but in the code defining the `debounce` factory / service / etc. My guess is it does not have the DI array defined.

Going out on a limb, I'd say you're using

[`bower_components/angular-debounce/src/debounce.js`](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-debounce/blob/v1.0.3/src/debounce.js) (no DI)

instead of

[`bower_components/angular-debounce/dist/angular-debounce.js`](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-debounce/blob/v1.0.3/dist/angular-debounce.js) (has DI)

Comment: Hit the nail on the head. I thought the error was pointing at the debounced function in in my controller but apparently not.

Comment: You're a hero. I copied an old factory definition and it didn't use the newer array syntax for DI, then got this error. Your comment about the DI array pointed me to the problem and one [] later it's all sorted :)